# Setting NavigationController as an initial controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two navigation controllers. How can I set the second one - `stopwatch` as an initial navigation controller?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.swipeBetweenVC = [Swipe new];
    [self setupRootViewControllerForWindow];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.swipeBetweenVC;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)setupRootViewControllerForWindow
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    Stopwatch *controller1 = (Stopwatch *)[storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Stopwatch"];
    UINavigationController *stopwatch = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller1];

    NamesController *controller2 = (NamesController *)[storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NamesController"];
    UINavigationController *namesList = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller2];

    self.swipeBetweenVC.viewControllers = @[namesList, stopwatch];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the stopwatch view first

```
 self.swipeBetweenVC.viewControllers = @[stopwatch, namesList];
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to have navigation controllers in that order (first = nameList, second = stopwatch) because I want to "slide back" from stopwatch to nameList

Comment: you want you initial view to have a "back" option?

Comment: That's exactly what I want

Comment: Is your swipeBetweenVC a UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have some Swipe type set up as a root VC, change to `self.window.rootViewController = stopwatch;`